# Secondary routes work while navigating in a heroku app singe page application but it fails on page reload

Tags: php, heroku, routes

I have a web app deployed on heroku of similar name - https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com. The web app is a single page app and uses PWA router and has routes similar to https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com/abc

When I run the app in localhost - https://localhost:2000 and use route https://localhost:2000/abc. These routes work on page refresh as well as on navigation. But when the same app is deployed on heroku the navigation works but secondary routes don't work on page refresh. That is if we go from https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com to https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com/abc we are able to see abc page but landing directly on https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com/abc throws a 404 error with following message -  "The requested URL /abc was not found on this server.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your routing is messed up. Now to correct that you need to add more information as to how you are deploying the application. Basically you need to rewrite server side routes to serve your index path by default.

Comment: prose was missing a few intended words